# Using a map that has a abstract base class pointer and calling a derived class function

Tags: c++, dictionary, inheritance, virtual, slice

I've searched on the web and can't find any solutions to my problem I hope you can help.

So I have constructed an abstract base class and have two derived classes that represents different experiments. (one is actually a derived derived class of my base class) And I made a map as such in a separate header file to store different types of experiments.

```
//Map class template to store name of experiment and the experiment within a project
typedef map <string, baseData <double>*> ExpContainer;

void search(string searchName, ExpContainer exps) {
    ExpContainer::iterator Iter;
    Iter = exps.find(searchName); //finds the entry corresponding to searchName and returns the iterator
    if (Iter != exps.end()) { //need this as if entry is not found, the return will be end iter.
        cout << "Found the experiment " << Iter->first << "." << endl;
        Iter->second->print();
    }
    else {

        cout << "Sorry, experiment " << searchName << " is not found" << endl;
    }

}
```

The print() function is different for each experiment type and I know there's a problem called slicing so I've made sure that print() is virtual in the base class. Here's my base class:

```
namespace mynmsp {

//base class of data can be measurements or errors
template < class T> class baseData { 

public:
    virtual void print() =0;
    virtual ~baseData() {
        cout << "Destructor called for the base class." << endl;
    }
};
}
```

Then in my main.cpp I've constructed different types of experiment and I want to print them. Each experiment class has different implementation of the print function that overrides the print function from the base class, like:

```
void print(){ //do something };
```

And in my main.cpp I have the map defined as:

```
ExpContainer project;
```

And after I have constructed each experiment, I've asked the user for the name of the experiment (expName) and inserted into project as such:

```
project[expName] =  &expC;
```

I think the insertion is fine as I tested the size of project and it was correct. 
However, a runtime error occured when my search function was called like this:

```
search(name, project);
```

I don't know if there's a problem with slicing or with my pointers? 
I tried to make print() a virtual function in each derived class but that doesn't seem to work either.

Apologies for the long question, please help!

Edit: I've constructed my experiments inside a do while loop while project is declared outside. The whole code is very long but its basics is something like this:

```
string repeatstr; //user input whether to repeat do while loop or not
bool repeat = true; //condition for staying inside do while loop
ExpContainer project; //declared project to store experiments

do {
    string expName;
    string ans1; //character to store user input
    cout << "What is the name of your experiment? " << endl;
    cin >> expName;
    cout << "Is this a experiment C ? (y/n)" << endl;
    cin >> ans1; 
       if(ans1 =="y"){ 
           //call the constructor for expC
           project[expName] = &expC;
        }else {
           //call the constructor for expB 
          project[expName] = &expB;
        }

    cout << "Do you want to enter another experiment?  (y/n)" << endl;
    cin >> repeatstr;
    if (repeatstr == "n") { repeat = false;  }

}while (repeat); //loop over this do-while loop while repeat is true

    cout << "There are " << project.size() << " in this database." << endl;

    //to retrieve info from a certain experiment
    string input, name;
    cout << "Would you like to retrieve any experiments (y/n)? " << endl;
    input = EitherInput("y", "n");
    if (input == "y") {
        cout << "Please enter the name of the experiment you want to retrieve: " << endl;
        cin >> name;
        search(name, project); //code breaks down here!
    }
```

Comment: Have you stepped through with a debugger?

Comment: Are you sure that the `expC` object actually lives longer than the map?

Comment: @KerrekSB , hello, thanks for your reply. I've constructed expC inside a do while loop and declared project outside the loop. So no, but I shoved expC into project inside the do while loop....so it should be fine? The size of project is also correct.

Comment: Hi @ArchbishopOfBanterbury , Thank you for your quick reply. I'm afraid I'm at an intermediate level of programming and have no clue how to use the debugger.....

Comment: It's useful to be able to use a debugger as early as possible as situations like this are easier to resolve through identifying the values of each variable at stages of execution. That said, it may be useful if you show the relevant parts of your `do-while` loop in the question here as that is likely where the problem is originating from.

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury , I've edited my question with the do while loop implementation as you advised. I hope its a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saving a pointer to the object that was already destroyed. You can check the addresses that you have in the map, most probably they are the same. You should store your experiment object in dynamic memory

```
if(ans1 =="y")
{ 
    project[expName] = new expC();
} // Scope ends here and all variable created in it will be destroyed.
else 
{
  project[expName] = new expB();
} // Scope ends here and all variable created in it will be destroyed.
```

And after you are done with them you need to call `delete` on each pointer to avoid memory leak. Also you need to check if the items in the map are already existing, otherwise you will loose pointers to allocated memory which is automatically a memory leak.

I would recommend you to use `std::share_ptr< baseData<double> >` instead of bare `baseData<double>*`. [Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) you can read more about it. And also consider using typedef in order to have more clear syntax.

---

P.S. 
The function

```
void search(string searchName, ExpContainer exps)
```

will copy whole map to its body. Use constant reference instead

```
void search(string searchName, const ExpContainer& exps)
```

But then you'll also need to declare function print as const:

```
virtual void print() const = 0;
```

and override it with const modifier:

```
virtual void print() const override;
```

And use constant iterator `ExpContainer::const_iterator Iter`

Comment: Thank you @teivaz , however I have  slight problem because my code is a bit more complicated than that after I constructed expC and expB, I have to manipulate them and then store them in project. Is no way I can store the manipulated experiments into project without 'new'? Like how you do .pushback in a vector?

Comment: `expC* myExperimentC = new expC();  project[expName] = myExperimentC; do stuff to myExperimentC;`

Comment: @AliS you can even use a reference to use dot operator instead of arrow: `expC& myExperimentCRef = * myExperimentC;`

Comment: also when I used `const` the following line 
 `Iter = exps.find(searchName); ` it has an error that :
no operator '=' matches these operands

Comment: The easy but wrong way is to remove const from argument. The right way would be to declare virtual function print as const and use const iterator. I'll update my answer

Comment: ahhh I see....Thank you so much @teivaz !! Its working perfectly now after I used 'new' and used the reference.
Though I still found it a bit weird how I can still modify expC after it has been inserted into project? 
Thanks again! My deadline is tmr and you saved me!!